# How to download youtube video into mp3, AND split by the 'time stamp'

Tags: python, youtube-dl

This is just one random vod for an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQA5DzUzMXk

```
It like this in comment(copy from above link so you do not need to enter):
0:00​ 白月光與朱砂痣 (song name)
2:00​ 不同顏色的悲傷
5:29​ 回憶格式化
9:21​ 該怎麼說再見
12:29​ 悄悄對你說
15:48​ 預示
19:13​ 失落
```

From the comment, you can see those are the time stamps for each song. I am able to download the whole video and convert into mp3 without problem. But it is possible to download by these time stamps?

*Side question:
We can set bit rate when convert into mp3, will this quality really matters? I see 128, and 320 have huge file size different. I know i won't tell different much by listen to them, but just curious about the true file bit rate are different or not, 320K can be higher quality? (no matter which video?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't with youtube-dl. You can, however, split whole file using `ffmpeg`; tricky, but possible:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "file.mp3" -to 00:01:59.999 track1.mp3
```

this saves your first track. You need some sort of scraping web page to obtain correct loop values!

*For your side question: use same bitrate you find in original file, as there's no way to increase quality in lossy compressed audio. 160 or 192  is a very acceptable quality. YouTube rarely offers more of 160, in my experience